# Examples of problems that cannot be formulated as optimization problems

Tags: optimization

An optimization problem has 3 main components: decision variables, constraints, and an objective function. Such a problem can be mathematically modelled and solved using an optimization solver. For example, a SUDOKU puzzle can be modelled as such and solved using a solver.

What are examples of famous real-life problems or puzzles that **cannot** be modelled as optimization problems? I reviewed relevant literature, but could not find any discussion on problems that cannot be modelled as optimization problems.

Comment: I’ve never seen the Goldbach conjecture formulated as an optimization problem. Maybe you’ll discover a way to do so? Best of luck!

Comment: @Aruralreader That's actually pretty simple: $\max_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \min_{p,q \in \text{Primes}} |2(n+2)-p-q| = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps you have in mind the part of an optimization problems that asks whether the constraints can be satisfied (consistency) or the *feasibility* subprogram.  It is common to approach such problems by adding an objective of no independent interest, thus converting the feasibility question into an optimization problem.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the selected level of abstraction and chosen classification. The question would be in the usability of this abstraction and the chosen classification of problems.

---

If you are allowed to assume that an *objective function* can mean a boolean function that is `true` if and only if the found solution satisfies the given constraints (rules of the puzzle) — then any [mathematical problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_problem) can be formulated in such a way.

Moreover, in the [first lecture notes of UC Berkely course CS278: Computational Complexity, Luca Trevisan says](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eluca/cs278-04/notes/lecture01.pdf):

> we will deal with four types of computational problems: decision problems,
> search problems, optimization problems, and counting problems. This distinction is useful and natural, but it is also arbitrary: in fact every problem can be seen as a search problem.

Now, I don't think that it would be an overextension to say that every *search problem* can be thought of as an *optimization problem*.

After writing this answer, I also found a discussion on [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37969). The additional piece there would be the mentioning of a *sampling problem*. However, even that is very arguable: [This paper by Scott Aronsson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/samprel.pdf) draws an equivalence on *sampling* and *searching*.